# Binding to a ListBox ItemsSource in Template in CustomControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, binding

I have an CustomControl with a ControlTemplate like this:

```
<ControlTemplate  x:Key="ListBoxInputControl" TargetType="{x:Type cc:InputControl}">
    <Grid 
        x:Name="ListRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition  SharedSizeGroup="Labels"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label...
        </Label>

        <ListBox
            x:Name="PART_ListBox"
            Grid.Column="1"  
            ItemsSource=....      // what goes here?      
            ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ListBoxItemTemplate}"
            Foreground="{TemplateBinding LblForeground}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding LblBackground}"
            
            SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding CbSelectedItem}">
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I need to link an XmlDataProvider to the ItemsSource through a Dependency Property "CbItemsSource".
This is what I have so far:

```
<ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="CrossSection" XPath="CheckList">
            <x:XData>
                <CheckList xmlns="">
                    <ListNode Title="Circ"/>
                    <ListNode Title="Oct"/>
                </CheckList>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
      
    </ListViewItem.Resources>
    <local:InputControl
        Template="{StaticResource ListBoxInputControl}"
        ListBoxItemTemplate ="{StaticResource ListNodeTemplate}" 
        CbItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CrossSection}, XPath=//ListNode, Mode=TwoWay}"
        LvSelectedIndex=...../>
</ListViewItem>
```

But that does not work.
I get an error:

```
Error       No matching constructor found on type 'System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable'. 
You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type.
```

I think the source binding in the line "CbItemsSource="{B..." is the problem.

What must I do?

Comment: Why don't you derive your control from ListBox? Use your ControlTemplate as Template for the ListBox and replace the PART_ListBox by an ItemsPresenter.

Comment: Or just use a regular listbox with templates and maybe a behavior. What does your control do that a listbox doesn't?

Comment: My Control has a Label and A ListBox, and sometimes I replace the ListBox by a ComboBox or TextBox (by replacing a template). In (my) practice it is more complicated than shown... So, the question remains.